# ui router keep the order of views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

i am trying to design a SPA that loads the parts of the page by order  ,

```
var main = {name : 'main',
    url  : "",
    abstract : true,
    views :{
    'header' : {//main template},
    'content' : {//main template},
    'footer' :{//main template}
}};
```

but when i make another state called "single_post" like

```
single_post = {name : 'single_post',
    url : "/sp",
    views : {
    'content' : {
    templateUrl : "some template" }
    }    
};

$stateProvider.state(main);
$stateProvider.state(single_post);
```

it loads the single_post template after loading the main !!
what i should do to keep the order of the views in the page ?

[image: XHR requests]

Comment: Can you be more clear with your question?

Comment: i am trying to display different states , all of them almost have the same views , but i want to change the middle view (content) for every state .

Comment: None of this is very clear....please take the time to read [ask]. Then [edit question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43428051/edit) with a properly detailed problem description

Comment: a simple `<ui-view>` in the right place will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `resolve`, this will not load your page until whatever written in resolve loads, for example:

```
$stateProvider.state('users.profile', {
  url: '/:id',
  templateUrl: 'views/users.profile.html',
  controller: 'UsersController',
  resolve: {
    user: function() {
      //function code
    },
    tasks: function() {
      //function code
    }
  }
});
```

In this, the page won't load until the user and tasks functions are executed.

Another option is to use the `$stateChangeSuccess` event listener to only call the controller function when the state has been successfully transitioned to. You can load a shell page here and populate when the controller returns data.